# How to add a Planner Tab to a Microsoft Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

How do I use Microsoft Graph to add tabs to an existing Channel.  In particular I want to add a Planner tab and a custom Web site Tab.  Looking at the graph I don't see a way to create Tabs.  I can see creating Channels, but not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph doesn't appear to have that functionality built in yet and I don't believe that the PowerShell modules do either.

Here's a reference to the Teams api overview: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview

I haven't come across anything for tabs.